# how to automatically update a slot of S4 class in R

Tags: r, r-s4

I was playing around with S4 objects in R and was wondering about the following:

Let's assume the following simplified example: We have two S4 classe within R, one called **Customer** and another **Order**. We define them with the following slots:

```
Customer <- setClass(Class = "Customer",slots = c(CustomerID = "numeric", Name = "character", OrderHistory = "data.frame"),
                     prototype = list(CustomerID = 0,Name = "",OderHistory = data.frame()))

Order <- setClass(Class = "Order",slots = c(CustomerID = "numeric", Description = "character",
                                               Cost = "numeric"), 
                     prototype = list(CustomerID = 0,Description = "",Cost = 0))


# constructor

Customer <- function(CustomerID, Name, OrderHistory=data.frame()){
  #drop sanity checks
  new("Customer",CustomerID = CustomerID, Name = Name, OrderHistory = OrderHistory)
}

Order <- function(CustomerID, Description = "",Cost = 0){
  #drop sanity checks
  new("Order",CustomerID = CustomerID, Description = "", Cost = 0)
}

#create two objects

firstCustomer <- Customer(1,"test")

firstOrder <- Order(1,"new iPhone", 145)
```

Obviously, firstCustomer and firstOrder are linked via the CustomerID. Is it possible to automatically update the OrderHistory slot of Customer once a new Order instance is created? Assuming that OrderHistory has two columns, "Description" and "Cost", how can I automatically update a new order instance? Is there a elegant / general way to do it? Most likely, the class Order needs a slot of type "Customer". Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't link across two independent objects, so you need methods that use both.  Here is an example with a replacement method:

```
Customer <- setClass(
  "Customer", 
  slots=c(
    CustomerID="numeric", 
    Name="character", 
    OrderHistory="list"
  ),
  prototype=list(OrderHistory = list())
)
Order <- setClass(
  Class="Order", 
  slot =c(
    Description="character", Cost="numeric"
) )

setGeneric(
  "add<-", 
  function(object, value, ...) StandardGeneric("add<-")
)
setMethod("add<-", c("Customer", "Order"), 
  function(object, value) {
    object@OrderHistory <- append(object@OrderHistory, value)
    object    
  }
)
setMethod("show", "Customer", 
  function(object) {
    cat("** Customer #", object@CustomerID, ": ", object@Name, "\n\n", sep="")
    for(i in object@OrderHistory) cat("\t", i@Description, "\t", i@Cost, "\n", sep="")
  }
)

firstCustomer <- new("Customer", CustomerID=1, Name="test")
add(firstCustomer) <- new("Order", Description="new iPhone", Cost=145)
add(firstCustomer) <- new("Order", Description="macbook", Cost=999)

firstCustomer
```

Produces:

```
** Customer #1: test

  new iPhone  145
  macbook 999
```

Answer (score 2):

The following doesn't add to @BrodieG's approach, but emphasizes that you probably want to model *tables* of Customers, Items, etc., rather than individual customers &c. Also, in many cases I think classes are like data base tables, and principles of good data base design probably apply to good class design (again remembering the S4 classes and R's copy-on-change semantics mean that the classes model *columns* rather than *rows* as in many other languages).

```
## Customers -- analogous to a data.frame or data base table
setClass(Class = "Customers",
  slots = c(CustomerId = "integer", Name = "character"))

## Items -- analogous to a data.frame or data base table
setClass(Class = "Items",
  slots = c(ItemId = "integer", Description = "character", Cost = "numeric"))

## Transactions -- analogous to a data.frame or data base table
setClass(Class="Transactions",
  slots = c(TransactionId="integer", CustomerId="integer", ItemId="integer"))
```

Probably you would provide some kind of explicit coordination between these tables

```
## Business -- analogous to a data *base*
Business = setClass(Class = "Business",
  slots = c(Customers="Customers", Items="Items", Transactions="Transactions"))
```

For a little completeness, here's a minimal implementation starting with some utility functions for generating sequential IDs and for updating object slots

```
.nextid <- function(x, slotName, n=1L)
    max(0L, slot(x, slotName)) + seq_len(n)

.update <- function(x, ...) {
    args <- list(...)
    for (nm in names(args))
        args[[nm]] <- c(slot(x, nm), args[[nm]])
    do.call("initialize", c(list(x), args))
}
```

The following add *vectors* of customers and items to the business

```
add_customers <- function(business, customerNames)
{
    customers <- slot(business, "Customers")
    len <- length(customerNames)
    initialize(business,
               Customers=.update(customers,
                 CustomerId=.nextid(customers, "CustomerId", len),
                 Name=customerNames))
}

add_items <- function(business, descriptions, costs)
{
    items <- slot(business, "Items")
    len <- length(descriptions)
    initialize(business,
               Items=.update(items,
                 ItemId=.nextid(items, "ItemId", len),
                 Description=descriptions, Cost=costs))
}
```

And finally record purchases in the transaction table; we'd want this to be more user-friendly, with a `purchase()` function taking customer and item names, and mapping these to customer and item IDs.

```
.purchase <- function(business, customerId, itemIds)
{
    transactions <- slot(business, "Transactions")
    len <- length(itemIds)
    initialize(business,
               Transactions=.update(transactions,
                 TransactionId=rep(.nextid(transactions, "TransactionId"), len),
                 CustomerId=rep(customerId, len),
                 ItemId=itemIds))
}
```

Here's our business in action

```
bus <- Business()
bus <- add_customers(bus, c("Fred", "Barney"))
bus <- add_items(bus, c("Phone", "Tablet"), c(200, 250))
bus <- .purchase(bus, 1L, 1:2)  # Fred buys Phone, Tablet
bus <- .purchase(bus, 2L, 2L)   # Barney buys Tablet
```

and our total sales (we'd want nice accessors for this)

```
> sum(bus@Items@Cost[bus@Transactions@ItemId])
[1] 700
```

R's copy-on-change semantics are likely to mean that this type of iterative update is *very* inefficient; we could be clever about this, or recognize that we're re-inventing an interface to a data base, and implement the back-end in SQL.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. From a pure OO perspective would you advice to not use BrodieG answers?

Comment: @user8 it's really your approach; BroadieG provided a good answer to your question (manually coordinate object updates, rather than finding an 'automatic' solution). Modelling objects as columns of tables is an R-centric (or maybe more generally column-oriented) OO approach; it wouldn't be appropriate in other languages, and is not appropriate for all OO situations.

Comment: @user8, as Martin suggests, there are compromises to using S4 for something that is really best suited as a data base.  If you are not leveraging the main benefits (inheritance, multiple dispatch), then it isn't clear the trade-offs are warranted just for the sake of argument validation.  You can also have a hybrid approach.  For example, the `add<-` method I wrote could easily just be an interface to a data base instead of to an internal list storage.